# P(A) given that P(A|B) and P(B) are known

Tags: conditional-probability

Given that $P(A \mid B)$ is known, and $P(B)$ is known, how can $P(A)$ be calculated? I tried using the definition of conditional probability - $P(A \mid B) = P(A \cap B)/ P(B)$ - to solve for $P(A \cap B)$ but I don't know where to go from there. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be.  To see this, let's look at a couple of examples:

First: suppose that you flip a fair coin twice, and let $A$ be the event that the first is heads and $B$ the event that the second is heads.  The coin flips are independent; so, in this case,
$$
P(A)=.5\qquad P(B)=.5\qquad P(A\mid B)=.5
$$

Second: say we again flip two fair coins, and again let $B$ be the event that the second is heads.  However, let $A$ be the event that BOTH are heads. Then
$$
P(A)=.25\qquad P(B)=.5\qquad P(A\mid B)=.5
$$

If there was a way to determine $P(A)$ from $P(B)$ and $P(A\mid B)$, then these two examples would need to have the same value for $P(A)$; but, they don't!

Comment: Uh, wouldn't the probability that the second flip is heads, *given that _both_ are heads* be 1.0?

Comment: The numbers would work if there were three coin tosses (and the middle one could be ignored for the first example).

Comment: Technically the question asks about $P(A|B)$ instead of $P(B|A)$

Comment: @BenJackson There, that should fix it.  Oy.

Answer (score 6):

In general, you can't calculate $P(A)$ from just $P(A \mid B)$ and $P(B)$ — you also need to know $P(A \mid \lnot B)$.

If you do know that, the calculation is easy enough:

$$\begin{aligned}P(A) 
&= P(A \land B) + P(A \land \lnot B) \\
&= P(A \mid B)P(B) + P(A \mid \lnot B)P(\lnot B) \\
&= P(A \mid B)P(B) + P(A \mid \lnot B)(1 - P(B))
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I know P(¬B) but not P(A∣¬B). Anything I can do?

Comment: Well, assuming $P(A\mid\lnot B)=0$ gives you a lower bound for $P(A)$, and assuming $P(A\mid\lnot B)=1$ gives you an upper bound.  That's pretty much it.

Comment: just realized that A and ¬B are disjoint, so P(A)=P(A∧B) which I already calculated using conditional probability equation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. If you found these answers helpful, you may want to mark one of them as [accepted](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark icon to the left of it.

Comment: Ok! I just did. Sorry, I am new here. This is a great community

Answer (score 5):

You don't have enough information to get $P(A).$

Consider a dice with six faces. Consider $A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{2\},B=\{2,4,6\}.$ It is $P(A_i/B)=\frac13$ and $P(B)=\frac{1}{2}.$ However $P(A_1)=\frac13$ and$P(A_2)=\frac16$