# Conditional Probability with Three Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I'm stuck on finding values related to C.

---

Assume 
$$ 
\begin{aligned} 
P(A) &= 0.3\\ 
P(B|A) &= 0.75\\ 
P(B|A′) &= 0.20
\end{aligned} 
$$  and 
$$
\begin{aligned} 
P(C|A \cap B) &= 0.20 \\ 
P(C|A′ \cap B) &=0.15 \\
P(C|A \cap B′ ) &= 0.80 \\
 P(C|A′ \cap B′) &= 0.90
\end{aligned}
$$
The relevant parts of the question are

(a) Find $P(A \cap B \cap C)$ and

(b) Find $P(B' \cap C)$

Hint: Draw a Venn diagram.
Recall that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B|A)$ and fill in the Venn diagram with the probabilities given in the problem.

This is from a homework assigment for a community college course titled, *Introduction to Probability and Statistics*, suitable for engineers.

The professor is using the ', the apostrophe symbol, for negation or set complement.

---

I have worked out (a) and most of (b).

For (a) I got $P(A \cap B \cap C)=0.045$
I also got $P(A\cap B) =0.225$, $P(A\cap C) =0.105$,$P(B\cap C) =0.066$
I have numbers for each possible area of the Venn diagram, except for I can't find $$P(C), P( (A \cup B \cup C)') \text{ or } P(C - (A \cup B))$$
I've got multiple equations written using two versions of Bayes theorem and the definition of conditional probability for various A, B, & C.  Of course to solve for two variables, I need two independent equations.  Likewise, three variables needs three independent equations, etc.  However, my equations all seem dependent on each other.  Trying to solve a system of dependent equations leads in circles or to infinitely many solutions.

---

Some context and motivation- I have a B.S. in Math.  This question is actually from a student I'm tutoring.  I promised him an answer, so am hoping for some help.  The student is not aware of the Wronskian or tests for independence of equations, so a simpler method would be better for him if possible.

Comment: I found this method https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851587/conditional-probability-pab-cap-c  which is adaptable, but I there must be a simpler method somewhere because even considering 13 simultaneous equations is way beyond this course.

Comment: Feel free to adjust my formatting for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part A**

The first part is quite straightforward. Simply use the provided hint twice:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)
&=P(C\mid A\cap B)\cdot P(A\cap B)\\
&=P(C\mid A\cap B)\cdot P(B\mid A) \cdot P(A)\\
&=0.20\cdot0.75\cdot0.30\\
&=0.045
\end{aligned}
$$

**Part B**

I am going to divide the second part into multiple steps. The first step is using the complement to obtain the probability of $A'$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A') &= 1-P(A)\\
&= 0.70
\end{aligned}
$$

Next, we can also use complement to find the following conditional probabilities' complements:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(B'\mid A\phantom{'})&=1-P(B\mid A\phantom{'})\\
&=0.25\\\\
P(B'\mid A')&=1-P(B\mid A')\\
&=0.80\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Using Bayesian formula just like the first part, we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A\phantom{'}\cap B')&=P(B'\mid A\phantom{'})\cdot P(A\phantom{'})\\
&=0.25\cdot0.30\\
&=0.075\\\\
P(A'\cap B')&=P(B'\mid A')\cdot P(A')\\
&=0.80\cdot0.70\\
&=0.56
\end{aligned}
$$

Last, we use $A\cup A'=S$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(C\cap B')
&=P(C\cap A\cap B') + P(C\cap A'\cap B')\\
&=P(C\mid A\cap B')\cdot P(A\cap B') + P(C\mid A'\cap B')\cdot P(A'\cap B')\\
&=0.80\cdot0.075+0.90\cdot0.56\\
&=0.564
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you so very much.  
I needed your fourth to last line, which begins $P( C \cap B')$ was the key I couldn't find.
The rest of question B is far, far simpler than my method.
This is wonderful.